# VBA Excel - Converts Word document from PDF in poor quality

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word

Good afternoon,

I would like to have the same quality of my .docx file transformed with .pdf by Excel VBA macro.
Is it possible?

I used the following code so far:

```
 Sub convertpdfword()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    

 Dim pdf_path As String
 Dim word_path As String

  pdf_path = ThisWorkbook.Path
  word_path = ThisWorkbook.Path

  Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
  Dim fo As Object
  Dim f As File

  Set fo = fso.GetFolder(pdf_path)

  Dim wa As New Word.Application
  Dim doc As Word.Document


  Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
  wa.Visible = True

  For Each f In fo.Files
  If fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name) Like "pdf*" Then
  Set doc = wa.Documents.Open(f.Path)
  doc.SaveAs2 (word_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".docx"))
  doc.Close False
  End If
  Next

  wa.Quit

  Application.StatusBar = ""

  MsgBox "All done"

  End Sub
```

and I am getting low quality of my .docx file as you can see below:

[image]

Is there a possibility to keep the same quality like by Foxit PDF-Save As option? Or shall I try with another programming language to do this?

Comment: You are using Word to open a pdf document. Using another programming language will make no difference as it is still Word doing the conversion.

Comment: You should realize that pdf is a format that often keeps just enough information to show the document correctly. That may be insufficient information to use it as a Word document. So Word --> pdf --> Word is not idempotent (does not result in the original Word document).

Comment: So does it mean, that the PDF reader -> save as option will be the best? I thought, that I can automatize it and get the word file straight away from pdf one.

Comment: The *quality* issue you seem to be having is just that the macro isn't saving the document with the right page size, or margins? Or is there more to the differences than we can tell from the low-res screenshot?

Comment: The first one... macro doesn't cope properly with sizes and margins. In the effect one page falls on 2 word pages. On the second page 2 rows come from 1st page, and rest of the page is empty. It firmly extends the file size and weight. Comparing to Foxit PDF my word file has 58 pages instead of 44 and 5,900KB weight instead of 2700KB (this is less important here).